# Maintaining Two Separate Software Versions From the Same Codebase in Version Control

Tags: version-control, workflows

Let's say that I am writing two different versions of the same software/program/app/script and storing them under version control. The first version is a free "Basic" version, while the second is a paid "Premium" version that takes the codebase of the free version and expands upon it with a few extra value-added features. Any new patches, fixes, or features need to find their way into both versions.

I am currently considering using `master` and `develop` branches for the main codebase (free version) along side `master-premium` and `develop-premium` branches for the paid version. When a change is made to the free version and merged to the `master` branch (after thorough testing on `develop` of course), it gets copied over to the `develop-premium` branch via the `cherry-pick` command for more testing and then merged into `master-premium`.

Is this the best workflow to handle this situation? Are there any potential problems, caveats, or pitfalls to be aware of? Is there a better branching strategy than what I have already come up with?

Your feedback is highly appreciated!

P.S. This is for a PHP script stored in Git, but the answers should apply to any language or VCS.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Instead of having two code version with a common base you should design your application in a way to make those premium features plug-able and driven by configuration rather than different code bases.

If you are afraid to ship those premium features (disabled by configuration) with the basic version you can still remove that code in a final build/packaging step and just have two build profiles.

Having this design you can also ship 5 different flavors and get very flexible, maybe even allowing third parties to contribute.

Comment: Yes this is what I started thinking about last night before I went to bed. Thanks!

Comment: modern Windows is designed this way, all versions have all the same code, and have features unlocked depending on the license key in use.

Answer (score 39):

I strongly recommend *not* using branches for this purpose. In general, you should consider branches for things that will be (or might be) merged back together again later (or for release branches, where you eventually stop development of one of the branches). In your case, you will never merge your "basic" and "premium" versions together, and they will both be maintained indefinitely, so branches are not appropriate.

Instead, maintain one common version of the source code and use conditional compilation (eg. `#ifdef` in C/C++, not sure what the equivalent is for PHP) to include or exclude the sections of code that differ between "basic" and "premium".

It looks like PHP might not have such a conditional compilation feature built in, so you could use the C preprocessor (`cpp`, you probably already have it) to preprocess your common source code and from that, produce a "basic" and a "premium" version without the preprocessor directives. Of course, if you choose to do this you should use `make` or something similar to automate the process of running the preprocessor.

Comment: What you are saying about branches makes total sense! Perhaps instead I could create a separate repo containing just the Premium code and use some sort of release script or a sub-module to combine it with the base code? This might make TDD harder, though...

Comment: Creating another repository is even worse than creating branches! You definitely want to choose a solution that involves the least duplication of versioned code.

Comment: The point of the second repo is to house *just* the extra code - not another copy of the whole app.

Comment: Ah I see, that would be more like the "plugin" model, where your basic code has the ability to load and run plugins (if they exist). The plugin code is separate and provides the premium features.

Comment: @Joseph: using two repos is only appropriate if the versioning of the two code bases is almost independent from each other. If that is not the case, I would strongly recommend to do what Greg wrote and keep everything in *one* repo. The only thing I would rethink is the use of the "C preprocessor". I guess a small script written in the language of your choice (PHP itself is fine, Perl or Python even better) which makes a copy of your code without the (somehwhat marked) premium features would do the trick.

Comment: @Joseph: and since you mentioned TDD: I guess the unit tests for your premium version are a superset of the ones for your basic version, so I guess your script can filter also the "basic" unit tests out, if you think that's necessary.

Comment: @GregHewgill what about keeping old versions of releases in source control? We currently have an "Active" folder, and when we get to a major release, we will create a version numbered folder for it and branch the "Active" folder to that version folder, so that version will always be the same, and we just keep working in the "Active" folder for all changes and updates. Is this an inappropriate use of branching, since there is no chance that we will ever, for example, merge the 1.2 version back into the "Active" version of the code base?

Comment: @Zack: Yes, release branches are also fine (I've updated my answer). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Zack, that is what tags are for. I typically have a `develop` branch, off of which I create feature branches. When a feature is completed, it is merged back to `develop`. When all code in `develop` has been thoroughly tested and is ready for production use, `develop` is merged into `master`. When a release is ready, a tag is created (ex. `1.0.0`) from `master`. This workflow is based off of the excellent [Driessen branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: please don't use the C Preprocessor as a general purpose text processor. 
Something like GPP is more appropriate (http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)

Answer (score 8):

We are using 2 separate projects, the Basic one and the Premium one that depends on Basic project. Do not use braches, they are usually used for features.

Comment: This appeals to me, because you can use your build script to automate  the creation of both basic and premium programs.

Comment: in general case you need 3 projects: common part, often organised as a library, and custom parts for two different versions.

Answer (score 3):

While most current answers are in favour of conditional compilation instead of branches, there is one scenario where there is a clear benefit to using branches: if you (now or later) decide to make the source code of the basic version available, including all the version history but excluding all the premium features, then you can do so with the branches approach but not with a single branch and conditional compilation.

I'd advise against cherry picking, and instead merge *all* changes from the basic version into the premium version. There should be no feature or bug fix included in the basic but missing in the premium version. To make things as painless as possible, you should make sure that the premium branch modifies the common files as little as possible. So the premium branch should mostly contain additional files, and perhaps some slight modifications to build instructions. That way, changes from the basic version will merge automatically without causing conflicts.

[Greg's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/244609/60223) suggested that you “consider branches for things that will be (or might be) merged back together again later”. With the approach I just described this is the case, except that the final branch for all commits will be `master-premium` not `master` (which is actually `master-basic`).

Sub-modules would of course be an option as well. It depends on your build process, but if you can make the premium version into a project which uses the basic version as a module, that would be just fine. You might however have a harder time if at some point you decide to cherry-pick features from the premium branch into the basic branch. With sub-modules such a change would be represented as two distinct commits, whereas with branches this would be a single commit to the basic version, and the next merge into the premium version would know that these changes are already included and don't have to be merged again.

Answer (score 0):

In “hardware” this is done often, they are systems sold to control the mess, sorry I can’t remember what they are called.

Once the “mid range” washing machine ships, it’s code is not change other than for a very important bug fix, even when the same code gets changed in the “low end” washing machine that ships  a few months later.

Customers don't expect to get upgrades to a washing machine they have already brought, a new model is also not shipped every few months.

Most of us don’t live in that world, so do what Greg says unless you are writing software for washing machines.