# Best practice for organizing code with checks for enabled feature

Tags: object-oriented

For example our App have Access Groups feature which may be enabled/disabled for the User.
So we would have multiple checking for feature status in different layers like:

```
if ($user->access_groups_enabled) {...}
```

This may be in all kinds of App layers, f.e. checking is needed for sql queries logic (if AG disabled then show all Posts instead of Posts which been attached to AG).

I hope it makes sense. So what is the best practice (project should use OOP) to do that in MVC context? Think as we have Laravel-based app.
I am thinking about polymorphism and Access Groups feature separation to module (like domain modules in DDD), then using AG-related objects by the same interface as we would use for non-related to AG modules. Multiple IF conditions allover the codebase realted to AG-feature checking smells somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding/disabling features for some users](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370897/hiding-disabling-features-for-some-users)

Comment: @gnat thanks, so as I understood right it would be good to f.e. setup IOC container to check if we enabled/disabled Feature for User to loaded appropriate AccessGroupsQuery vs CommonQuery?

Comment: @Clark: Where did you read "IOC container" in my (or any other) answer to that potential duplicate question?

Comment: @Clark I think your question is about authorization. The provided link by gnat should be helpful to you. How you implement it depends on how much control you want, let`s say by module (like access to a whole page) or by action (some buttons will be disabled/hidden). You'll normally request the authorization at app load (or at the start of every page), have an authorization object and then render your components accordingly.

Comment: @DocBrown I didn't, I just guessed where should I put my single-entry-point config for features management so I could inject Access Groups feature Query instead of common Query class which I used when AG feature disabled. I hope it makes sense. For example in Laravel framework context.